# Under what kind of circumstance could we deduce that the integral of some composition of trigonometric function is zero from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I find that there are some very strange looking integrals of composition of trigonometric functions for which I either cannot compute or is very tedious to do so, for example, it seems that the integral of the function:

$\cos\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr) \sin(x)$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ is $0$

can be deduced without any computations at all. Why is this so? Is there any nice criteria of which we could use?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto \cos \cos x \sin x$ is periodic of period $2 \pi$ (because $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are, too), so the integral over an interval of length $2 \pi$ is the same for every such interval; in particular,
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos \cos x \sin x \,dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos \cos x \sin x \,dx .$$
The integral on the r.h.s. is the integral of an odd function over an interval symmetric about the origin, so it is zero:
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos \cos x \sin x \,dx = 0}} .$$

Answer (score 2):

For the function that you mentioned, what happens is that, if $x\in[0,2\pi]$,$$\cos\bigl(\cos(2\pi-x)\bigr)\sin(2\pi-x)=-\cos\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)\sin(x)\text,$$and therefore\begin{align*}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)\sin(x)\,dx&=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\bigl(\cos(2\pi-x)\bigr)\sin(2\pi-x)\,dx\\ &=-\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)\sin(x)\,dx.\end{align*}That's why the integral is equal to $0$.